# Cmd + shift + V not working in safari

Tags: safari, shortcut

Shortcuts such as <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (paste plain text) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> (comment out many lines in Overleaf) do not work in Safari, but do in Chrome. I have followed many tutorials about cleaning Safari cache and other stuff but none worked.

I am on a M1 pro MacBook Pro.

Any ideas?

Comment: as @benwiggy pointed already out Safari will paste plain text using _Command + V_. As shown in the [overview of Overleaf short cuts](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/overleaf-keyboard-shortcuts/qykqfvmxdnjf) the toggle to comment a line can vary depending on wether you use a non-us or us keyboard layout: _Command + ß_ or _Command + /_ might work on your system in Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such shortcut, nor menu command for "Paste Plain Text" in Safari.

There is one for "Paste and Match Style", which pastes the text in the same style as the style at the insertion point.

[image]

As you can see, its shortcut it Command Shift Alt V.

Chrome may well have different shortcuts from Safari.

Safari's cache mainly concerns web content, and is unlikely to affect menu shortcuts.

Comment: this appears to be a bug, the matching of style appears to be the same behavior of both paste and paste with matching style; so frustrating in Safari to not have plain text option (gmail emails I compose end up with completely illegible text because the composition and result look different due to unintended rich text colors, etc)